# extract audio as a MP3 file from video c#

Tags: c#-4.0, audio, video, ffmpeg, avi

I want to extract audio from a video file as a MP3 using c#. The bit-rate of the audio should be able to specify. Could someone please help me on this? I have already looked at "whether" but I'm not sure whether it is possible to do with "whether" without prompting CMD.

Please don't suggest me following article. it doesn't work properly for file that are larger than 700mb 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

Comment: you're not understanding how it works. the avi file won't magically provide you whatever bitrate you want. you extract whatever audio's embedded in there, **THEN** you convert to your desired bitrate. if you want >700meg avi, then don't look for standard avi libraries. the avi format as spec'd by MS never did support large files.

Comment: Would calling an ffmpeg binary (or using libffmpeg) count as a solution? Because if not then you'll be in for a whole lotta trouble.

Comment: @MarcB my understanding is that the poster wants to specify the bitrate of the MP3 output.  I assume it would be AVI->PCM->MP3 because audio in AVI doesn't have to be mp3 encoded.  AVI is just a wrapper.  He probably wants to control the fidelity of the second stage encoding.  Also, AVI has a 2GB limit.

Comment: @MarcB, I'm aware the fact that .avi file will not magically provide whatever the bit-rate i request. but I want to limit the bit-rate to 128. so that's what i meant. It would be really great if you could help me on this sir.

Comment: @Magnus, is it possible to use "ffmpeg" with .net c#? if so, does it have the ability to perform the .avi to MP3 conversion without displaying the command-prompt?

Comment: @thang, you got it correct, I want to specify the bit-rate of the MP3 file e.g (128, 256). what do you mean by saying that.avi has a "2 GB limit"?

Comment: the hard limit is actually 4gb, but depending on how the reader works, the 2gb limit may be there (from using signed instead of unsigned for pointer, i think).  for details, see http://www.avi-io.com/2_4_gig_issue.htm

Comment: @PIKP ffmpeg will be able to do the conversion and you can suppress the console window that would normally open. See my answer below for a link that describes the general process.

Answer (score 0):

You could call an ffmpeg binary without creating a separate console window. I'd assume C#/.NET has templates for that, but if not then the WinAPI way to do it is to specify the ffmpeg command to run and dummy handles for stdin/stdout in your CreateProcess() call. Something like that is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx