# C# Getting Windows Universal API into Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, win-universal-app

I have a C# Winforms application that needs an API.

```
// The API that I need
using System.Windows.Media.Transcoding;
```

However I kept getting a problem saying that the namespace couldn't be found. After many hours of searching I finally concluded that the API is only available for Windows Universal applications. This is a problem because I need to use that API in my project to fix an annoying problem.

Does anyone know how to get Windows Universal API's into a Winforms application?

Comment: What is 'the annoying problem' ?

Comment: I need to get the Audio from a video file as a Byte[]

Comment: But won't that also include the Video bytes? I only want the Audio bytes

Comment: Sorry, i misread your comment. What format is the video file, or are you looking for a universal type solution.

Comment: Yea, im looking for a universal type solution.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326268/extract-audio-as-a-mp3-file-from-video-c-sharp and see if that leads you in the right direction. A UWP API library will not work with Winforms, however you could build a UWP app that does what you need and call it from your winforms project

Comment: Thxs,  didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Post it as an answer, ill accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UWP API library will not work with WinForms, however if you are desperate to use that API then you could build a UWP app that does what you need and call it from your WinForms project.